# struts2: problem in assigning a variable value to checkbox

Tags: struts2

I am working on struts2. In my jsp page I want to assign the value of a string variable to a checkbox (when it is checked by user). I tried it many times like -

```
<% String code = "decompose"; %>
```

First example:

```
<tr><td>              
<s:checkbox name="codeCkBox" fieldValue="%{‘code’}" onclick="submit()"/>
</td></tr>
```

Second example:

```
<tr><td>              
<s:checkbox name="codeCkBox" value="%{‘code’}" onclick="submit()"/>        
</td></tr>
```

Third example:

```
<tr><td>           
<s:set name="setCkBoxValue" value="%{‘code’}"/>              
<s:checkbox name="codeCkBox" fieldValue="# setCkBoxValue" onclick="submit()"/>       
</td></tr>
```

But everytime when I tried to get this value by checkbox name it returns variable name i.e “code”.
Looking for a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing `${code}` instead of `${'code'}`?

Comment: Hi Pablo Fernandez,
I tried both ${code} and ${'code'} and this time its throwing an exception i.e "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute fieldValue does not accept any expressions
". Any other solution ?

Comment: Pablo Fernandez , Its working but I did it differently. See my jsp snippet-
String userId = "58835";
request.setAttribute("userId ", userId );
<s:checkbox name="ckbox1" fieldValue="%{#request.userId }"/>
Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 0):

did u include your struts directive? i ask because its only showing 'code' which could mean its ignoring the struts

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr><td> <s:checkbox name="codeCkBox" value="%{#code}"
 onclick="submit()"/> </td></tr>
```

try the above code. since code is the  JSP variable therefore it should be accessed with a # in front of its name rather than with a quote. Hope this helps